# place editText below component in relativeLayout, but component fills screen?

Tags: java, android, terminal, android-edittext, android-relativelayout

I have a `linearLayout`, inside which is a `relativeLayout`, in the `relativeLayout` to want to place an `EditText` field below a terminal emulator view. However when I do so nothing appears? i assume it is below it off screen?!
Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLRrL.png
How do I place it below at the bottom of the screen? to push up the terminal?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
android:background="@drawable/wallpaper"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


   <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/topButtons" 
    android:layout_margin="4dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button android:id="@+id/deviceConnect"
        android:layout_margin="8dip"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Connect"/>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="8dip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:text="Connected Adapter:"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <Spinner android:id="@+id/deviceSpinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/currentSettings" 
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
                android:text="Current Settings: Not Connected"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="8dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:text="Baud:"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <Spinner android:id="@+id/baudSpinner"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="8dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:text="Data:"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <Spinner android:id="@+id/dataSpinner"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="8dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:text="Parity:"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <Spinner android:id="@+id/paritySpinner"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="8dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:text="Stop:"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <Spinner android:id="@+id/stopSpinner"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button android:id="@+id/updateSettings"
        android:layout_margin="8dip"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Update\nSettings"/>
</LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <Button android:id="@+id/Command"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enable"/> 

   <Button android:id="@+id/Command2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Configure"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Command"/> 

   <Button android:id="@+id/Command3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Exit"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Command2"/> 

   <Button android:id="@+id/Command4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Version"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Command3"/> 

   <Button android:id="@+id/Command5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Run"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Command4"/> 

    <Button android:id="@+id/Command6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Backspace"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Command5"/> 

        <Button android:id="@+id/Command7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Backspace2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Command"/> 


    <jackpal.androidterm.emulatorview.EmulatorView
    android:id="@+id/emulatorView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Command7"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Command" />

     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/term_entry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionNone|flagNoExtractUi"
        android:inputType="text|textImeMultiLine"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Command7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/emulatorView" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/term_entry_send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/entry_send"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/term_entry" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/emulatorView"/>

    </RelativeLayout>  

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want the `EditText` to be placed right below the emulator view or at the bottom of the `RelativeLayout` no matter of the emulator view's height?

Comment: I'd like it to always be at the bottom of the terminal but that it can't be hidden and when the keyboard comes up it would be placed above the keyboard. I can do this fine if it is all a linearlayout.

Comment: Most likely your emulator view is pushing the `EditText` out of the screen. Did you override the `onMeasure` method of the `EmulatorView`?

Comment: No I've never used onMeasure, I'll look it up now. The emulatorview is just a terminal emulator library I am using.

Comment: align button and edit text on bottom of parent an instead of setting layout_below to edittext and button set layout_above to emulatorview.